# Mixed mode .NET 4.0 assembly refuses to load in Windows 10 Pro but loads fine in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, .net-assembly, mode, mixed

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Solution with a WPF project that provides a GUI for a mixed mode DLL project (let's call it xxxxx.DLL) in that same solution.

Now on Windows 10 Home the WPF project loads fine (both inside and outside of the VS2012 debugger) and there is no trouble loading the mixed mode DLL. But if I try this on Windows 10 Pro (outside any debugger) I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'xxxxxx.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could
> not be found.

I already know the error message is wrong and misleading because I added the following test code to my application that is executed before the DLL gets loaded:

```
        var executingAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var executingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executingAssembly.Location);
        var DLLpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(executingFolder, "xxxxxx.DLL");
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Calling ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(" + DLLpath + ")");
        try
            {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(DLLpath);
            }
        catch (Exception dlle)
            {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dlle.ToString(), "ELWAVE Pro - ChartWindow constructor");
            }
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Returned from ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom");


        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Calling LoadFile(" + DLLpath + ")");
        try
            {
            //System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(DLLpath);
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(DLLpath);
            }
        catch (Exception dlle)
            {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dlle.ToString(), "ELWAVE Pro - ChartWindow constructor");
            }
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Returned from LoadFile");
```

The call to ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom succeeds but the call to LoadFile (or UnsafeLoadFrom) produces the same 'file not found' error.

I checked with .NET Reflector if I was missing any dependencies on the Windows 10 Pro system but that does not appear to be the case.

I also checked with Fusion++ (easier to use version of fuslogvw.exe) and it shows the following with regard to this DLL:

```
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxx\xxxxxx.dll.
```

I don't know if this is significant though, this warning also shows for WpfToolkit and WPFToolkit.Extended and System.Drawing.

From all this it appears that the DLL can be found, but that for some reason the CLR runtime refuses to load it. Since this behavior is different on Windows 10 Home (where it does load) and Windows 10 Pro (where it does NOT load and produces this error), I'm wondering if there are some default security policies on Windows 10 Pro that might cause this.

Incidentally I have tried creating a small test project that has this problem but that does not appear to be as trivial as I had hoped. A very simply 5 line mixed-mode assembly did load fine on Windows 10 Pro so there is more going on.

I forgot to mention: both projects target .NET <s>Platform</s> Framework 4.0. The GUI used to be on 4.5 but I changed it back to 4.0 just in case this contributed to the problem.

Also, the DLL does not have a strong name right now (ie. it's not signed). Could that be a problem specifically on Windows 10 Pro?

If anybody has any suggestions on how to further investigate and especially solve this problem I would be very grateful. I hope to be able to avoid stepping through the code with <s>ILSpy</s> dnSpy and even with that I'm not sure I will be able to find a solution.

Added: I forgot to mention that for the WPF GUI app the Platform target is x86 and the mixed mode DLL is also 32 bit.

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" is surely the underlying problem.  A mixed-mode assembly also has a dependency on the C++ runtime DLLs.  Tends to be available by accident but you never mentioning taking care of them on this machine is a red flag.  Double-check with Process Monitor or dumpbin.exe /imports, deploy with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

Comment: That was my first thought as well and I thought I had checked that sufficiently. However I just noticed that .NET Reflector doesn't appear to show all dependencies and the output of Depends is also not always too helpful. I will try your suggestions. I really do hope it's something as easy as a missing dependency. Just recently I found out that Assembly.Load(byte[]) doesn't work with mixed-mode assemblies and I was beginning to worry that I was running into something similar here.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I was able to fix this using dumpbin (I used /dependents instead of /imports). Before I posted I had copied msvcr110.dll to the application folder but it turns out msvcp110.dll was _also_ needed. It now runs fine, thank you so much!

If you post your original comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.